# Schedule Task in java using Timer

Tags: java, timer, timezone, scheduled-tasks

I have created timezone specific schedule task event using java. My code is bellow.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"));
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Runs everday morning 12.00 AM");
    }
 }, date.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

But the problem is when call to this method it runs this task soon. I need to run this job 12.00 in Asia/Colombo time zone every day. How to do that?

Comment: What timezone is set on the server and what time does it run?

Comment: I am runing locally now. So asia/colombo now. any help??

Comment: When does it actually run?

Comment: I defined it to be run when the web application deploying using web.xml Now I need to make that code to execute the task first time when the time is 12.00 am in specific time zone. I think date.getTime() make that run on that time. What is the fault?

Comment: By the way, you should not use Timer in Web apps (Servlets or Java EE environments). Look at [ScheduledExecutorService]( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead. And look at ServletContextListener as a place to setup and schedule the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scheduling your first execution in the past (midnight of the current day), and therefore your task will be executed immediately.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)):

> [...] if the scheduled first time is in the past, it is scheduled for immediate execution.

The easiest way to fix this, is by adding 1 day to your scheduled first execution time:

```
date.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

---

Additionally, you probably want to schedule the execution of this task as **fixed rate** instead of **fixed delay**. If you don't, your task will be executed a little bit later every day, depending on the actual time it takes to complete the task. Again, see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)) for details.

Comment: So how to set it to be execute to next day that time?